# How to run multiple PHP apps on a single LAMP instance

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am running a single PHP app on a single EC2 instance with LAMP setup. I have pointed my domain to the elastic IP. So currently if I web browse to the elastic IP or the domain, it directly opens my clients website which is in the usual var/www/folder1. Now he requires me to setup a CRM on the same instance. I have created a folder2 and placed all the required files in it. I just want the CRM to open at elasticip/folder2 (54.244.213.43/folder2). Now because of the routing in my existing application, the above url leads to a 404. Is it possible to do what I need?

Another way to do this may be by adding another elastic IP, but my virtual host settings display nothing about the elastic ip so how do I point the new elastic ip to the other folder (folder2)?

My current VirtualHost settings are as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder1
    <Directory /var/www/folder1/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not the best with VirtualHost settings so I don't know how I can changes these around to make sure the crm app also runs fine. If possible I would like to do it with the existing IP or else any other method would do.

Thanks!

Comment: if u want both sites on the same ip you have 2 options: 1) name-based hosting (google it) or 2) symlink folder2 into folder1's docroot / or change the host doc/root up one dir with a default .htaccess or index into folder1

Comment: I don't mind adding another IP. But I just tried, I cannot associate more than 1 elastic IP to my instance. It removes the association with the existing IP.

Comment: @user16081 Symlink wont work since placing the actual folder2 inside folder2 doesn't work. Can you explain the third part of the comment: "change the host doc/root up one dir with a default .htaccess or index into folder1"?

Answer (score 2):

Simply Add another virtualhost entry if in case you want to assign diifferent domain name later :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder2
    <Directory /var/www/folder2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

OR

if you just want access it just like example.com/folder
than just add folder inside the directory /var/www/folder1/ named folder2.

Comment: I tried both your methods. Neither works. I added another Virtual Host , nothing changed and adding the folder2 inside folder1 doesn't work since the existing application is a Symfony2 app which runs on routing component.

Comment: Check this for symfony2,it was not mentioned in question before and also make sure mod_rewrite module is enabled on you server.  https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.2/web/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to your problem is move folder /var/www/folder2 inside folder1 i.e. it should work like

/var/www/folder1/folder2

It will work when you browse the subfolder through the url .

Comment: This will not work, as I mentioned in the question, the routing of the existing app in folder1 will lead the url to a 404...